# What should be in the build.gradle file to support imports of the standard groovy libraries

Tags: maven, groovy, import, repository, gradle

I had created a groovy project. It worked by itself.

After some additions I had to add a new jar of a new library into the imports.

While the whole workspace runs on Gradle, I added the appropriate Maven reference to the gradle.build file.

After running `gradle cleanEclipse Eclipse` the new library works OK.

But. All project references to the Groovy libraries disappeared. Foolish me, I had to put some references to them into the gradle.build, too.

The list of libraries:

```
groovy.util.slurpersupport
groovy.xml
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.xml
groovy.lang
```

But I don't know how to include them into gradle.build. I can't found them in maven repository. And even so, I have them installed in my Eclipse, and I should take these. And I can't google any help, because gradle groovy gives the results on how to call gradle from groovy, not vice versa.

[Moving from plain Groovy to Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526431/moving-from-plain-groovy-to-gradle) won't help, it is really about gradle support for calling a java library from groovy.

I have nothing against getting dependencies from Maven rep., but I don't know how to do it in my case - The problem is, that I have Eclipse 3.6. And I should use the last version of groovy for Eclipse 3.6. So, I have installed it from http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/. And I don't know what is the equivalent version in Maven - there is no info about it.

Comment: Why isn't the usual (as of Gradle 1.4+) `dependencies { compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.2" }` (or whatever version you need) good enough? All Groovy releases are available from Maven Central.

Comment: The problem is, that I have Eclipse 3.6. And I should use the last version of groovy for Eclipse 3.6. So, I have installed it from http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/.

Comment: There is a difference between the Groovy distribution and the Eclipse Groovy plugin. The latter ships with and uses its own Groovy distribution. Nevertheless you should declare one for the Gradle build as well.

Comment: Yes, that is what I desire to do - to 'declare one for the Gradle'. But how can I do it, please? What have I to declare, exactly? All plugins in Eclipse that have "groovy" in their names?

Comment: I've already shown how to declare the Groovy distribution. You can't declare the Eclipse Groovy plugin. Either each developer installs it himself, or you create a custom Eclipse distribution for your team/company.

Comment: "Either each developer installs it himself" - I have done it(installed from http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.6/). But after 'gradle cleanEclipse eclipse' for the project, it won't work in this very project. Eclipse won't see groovy's libraries. (could you make an answer from your comments - already you helped me , so I could vote for it)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27778/discussion-between-gangnus-and-peter-niederwieser)

Comment: I suggest to seek help on the groovy-eclipse mailing list. I'd also try with a recent plugin version (which I think is only available for Eclipse 3.7 and higher).

Answer (score 0):

There was some error in the groovy in Eclipse installation. Now after running `gradle cleanEclipse Eclipse` while build.gradle has NO dependencies to groovy, almost everything runs OK, I only have to add the groovy nature to the project