# How can I set in build.gradle the groovy nature of an Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle

After running `gradle cleanEclipse Eclipse` on the project it loses the Groovy nature. How can I set this nature automatically, or simply to say to the Gradle to leave it alone.

Edit: 
According do [doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseProject.html), I can write in the build.gradle:

```
eclipse {
  project {
    natures 'some.extra.eclipse.nature', 'some.another.interesting.nature'
  }
}
```

But what is the name of the groovy nature, or how could I get it?

I go to the .project and look:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>bndtools.core.bndnature</nature>
</natures>
```

org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature - that is the nature name

And I am adding `apply plugin: "groovy"`, as @Peter Niederwieser advised (thanks+1)

### But

After running `gradle cleanEclipse Eclipse` I have correct .project file, and the project has "G" on the icon, but in the .classpath two lines are not present:

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_SUPPORT"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"/>
```

That ARE present, when I am setting the Groovy nature by hand.

And it seems, that these lines are important, for in that variant the project shows errors even on compile level - it doesn't see some Groovy methods.

Comment: Still running on an old version of Eclipse?  If so, as you didn't get an answer to this [when you asked it before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840408/what-should-be-in-the-build-gradle-file-to-support-imports-of-the-standard-groov), I would follow the advice Peter Niederwieser gave you and ask on the groovy-eclipse mailing list

Comment: I am not the only one person who works on the project. Yes, it is 3.6 and I can't change it yet.

Comment: @tim_yates And the problems are with Gradle, not with Eclipse. And the Gradle is of the last version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that for a real groovy nature setting, I need  not only to set

```
natures.add 'org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature'
```

and

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
```

, but also to edit the classpath.

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            withXml {
                Node node = it.asNode()
                node.appendNode('classpathentry',[exported:"true",kind:"con",path:"GROOVY_SUPPORT"]) 
                node.appendNode('classpathentry',[exported:"true",kind:"con",path:"GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is interesting, if we turn on the groovy classpath by hand, only the path "GROOVY_SUPPORT" appears in the .classpath file. It is also enough for my project. But when turning by hand the whole Groovy nature, both paths appear. So, I am better including them both, too.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about this again, Gradle will add a Groovy nature for those projects that have the `groovy` (or `groovy-base`) plugin applied. So either add that plugin on the Gradle side, or don't run `cleanEclipse` after you have added the Groovy nature manually, or switch to the [Eclipse Gradle tooling](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle) instead of generating Eclipse files.

Comment: And how can I add that groovy plugin to the project on the Gradle side?

Comment: I simply can't change to Eclipse 3.7. So, I can't use the Eclipse Gradle Tooling. (I wanted to do it for long ago). And I can't not clean Eclipse or at least the "classpath", because it is just the classpath I need to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle-Eclipse plugin (that is gradle tooling for Eclipse, not the Eclipse plugin for gradle). Should be installable on Eclipse 3.6.  (I say *should* be installable because we no longer test on 3.6, but there shouldn't be any reason why it is broken).  If you install this plugin, you should be able to import your gradle project into Eclipse without calling `gradle Eclipse`.

You can install from the update site here:

http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle

And more information on the project is here:

https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that @Peter Niederwieser already had given the reference to that tool, and it is written there, that the minimal Eclipse version for it is 3.7 :-(