# NoClassDefFoundError...org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLineParser when Run As, Groovy Script

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle, eclipse-kepler

I just installed Eclipse KEPLER and am trying to bring all my projects back in from github.  The projects are all gradle projects so my procedure is pretty much...

1. Clone the git repo
2. gradle eclipse
3. Import Project into Eclipse

Everything seems to be fine, except I can't "Run As, Groovy Script" the scripts within the project.  When I try, the console spews...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLineParser
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

.  Interestingly enough, I can "Run As, Java Application" without issue.  Its definitely a Groovy project as it has the G in the project icon.  What does the stacktrace mean and how do I overcome it?

The repository that is causing my issue is at https://github.com/robertkuhar/StackOverflow

My gradle is 1.11 on groovy 1.8.6 in eclipse kepler with the Groovy-Eclipse plug-in Version: 2.8.0.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE

Comment: Which version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Gradle 1.11 on groovy 1.8.6

Comment: It doesn't appear that this worked in JUNO either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when creating the "Groovy Script" run configuration, the main class is set to `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter` instead of the script you are intending to run. Replacing it with the Groovy class/script you would like to run sorts the issue.

**Update**

After some digging the way to solve the issue is:

- Remove the Groovy dependency from the Gradle build.
- Configure the project classpath and nature, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968141/how-can-i-set-in-build-gradle-the-groovy-nature-of-an-eclipse-project)

**build.gradle**

```
eclipse {
    project {
        natures.add 'org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature'
    }
    classpath {
        file {
            withXml {
                Node node = it.asNode()
                node.appendNode('classpathentry',[exported:"true",kind:"con",path:"GROOVY_SUPPORT"]) 
                node.appendNode('classpathentry',[exported:"true",kind:"con",path:"GROOVY_DSL_SUPPORT"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does, indeed, work (Changing the debug configuration from org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter to a specific class), but I am surprised that I needed to do this.  The non "gradle eclipse" projects work fine through the org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.  I'm beginning to thing "gradle eclipse" is setting up the environment wrong.  This feels more like a work around than a solution, but it unblocks me.

Comment: It do look like something is missing in the configuration created by Gradle. Tried applying the methods suggested in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968141/how-can-i-set-in-build-gradle-the-groovy-nature-of-an-eclipse-project) but it did not solve the issue

Comment: Hey, thanks.  Something just like this ended up working.  I have to leave the compile dependency on groovy in or else the straight-up gradle build fails.  But leaving it in and adding the eclipse task override you describe seems to do the trick.  I suspect if I I want to move to groovy 2.x I may have trouble, but that is a challenge for another day.  Thanks again.